# Set PowerShell variable with environment variable or a default if not present

Tags: bash, powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to set a variable in a PowerShell script from either an Environment Variable or a default if the `$env` value isn't specified. I can do something similar in Bash by doing the following.

```
BASH_VAR_IN_SCRIPT=${MY_ENV_VAR:="default value"}
```

Is there something similar in PowerShell? My Google-fu isn't returning what I am looking for. I am using PowerShell Core 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$env:MY_ENV_VAR` will return `null` if `MY_ENV_VAR` isn't defined, so you can use the null-coalescing operator `??` to specify a default value:

```
$myVar = $env:MY_ENV_VAR ?? "default value";
```

This only [works in Powershell 7+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7#null-coalescing-assignment-and-conditional-operators). For older versions, you can use an if-statement:

```
$myVar = if ($env:MY_ENV_VAR) { $env:MY_ENV_VAR } else { "default value" };
```

Comment: I should've mentioned I was using PowerShell Core 7. I've added that to my question now.