# How does powershell handle default-value-if-null in a variable declaration?

Tags: powershell

For example, in BASH I can write:

```
# if foo is empty, it will equal 'bar'
foo=${foo:='bar'}
```

How would I do that in powershell? Ideally, I can set a parameter's default value to an environment variable that defaults to a literal, written for communication purposes in pseudo code:

```
param(
  $foo=${env:foo:='bar'} # in pseudo code
)
```

How does powershell handle this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set PowerShell variable with environment variable or a default if not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548561/set-powershell-variable-with-environment-variable-or-a-default-if-not-present)

Comment: if you want to handle the condition inside the `param` block, you would need to use `$(...)` i.e.: `param($foo = $( <# condition inside #> )...`. personally wouldn't recommend that, much better to handle this in the blocks. I believe Abdul's link answers this otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Windows PowerShell*:

```
param(
  $foo = ($env:foo, 'foo')[$null -eq $env:foo]
)
```

Note:

- This takes advantage of the fact that when a Boolean expression such as `$null -eq $env:foo` is used as an *array index*, `$true` is coerced to `1`, and `$false` to `0`, so that the appropriate array element is returned.

  - Note: It is not a concern here, but due to use of an array literal, *all* array elements are evaluated *up front*, before the element of interest is extracted.
- The conceptually clearer (and short-circuiting), but more verbose alternative is to use a regular `if` statement, which, however, requires enclosure in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--):

  ```
  param(
    $foo = $(if ($null -eq $env:foo) { 'foo' } else { $env:foo })
  )
  ```

---

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can use `??`, the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-coalescing-operator-):

```
param(
  $foo = $env:foo ?? 'foo'
)
```